# Angular: Get length of instances in array

Tags: arrays, angularjs

Not sure exactly how to explain it but what i am trying to do is return the amount of times "Jack" is the string attached to the winner property in my array.

```
     function myCtrl($scope) {
       $scope.data = [{
         game: 1,
         dnscore: 10,
         bwscore: 9,
         winner: "Jack"
       }, {
         game: 2,
         dnscore: 9,
         bwscore: 10,
         winner: "Jill"
       }, {
         game: 3,
         dnscore: 9,
         bwscore: 10,
         winner: "Jill"
       }, {
         game: 4,
         dnscore: 6,
         bwscore: 10,
         winner: "Jill"
       }];
     };
```

Then be able to bind {{jackwins}} into my document.
Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You may do it this way:

Change your `data` array with function `add`:

```
function myCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.data = [];
    $scope.add = function(dt){
        data.push(dt);
        if(dt.winner == "Jack")
            $scope.jackwins++;
    }
    $scope.jackwins = 0;
};
```

**UPD.**
Or you may do it via function - this way is more flexible

```
function myCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.data = [
        {winner:"Jack", ...},
        {winner:"Jimm", ...}
    ];
    $scope.getWinsCount = function(name){
        var c = 0;
        for(var i=0;i<$scope.data.length;i++){
            if(name==$scope.data[i].winner)
                c++;
        }
        return c;
    };
};
```

Than you is your html you call it like this `<div>{{getWinsCount('Jack')}}</div>`

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.jackWinCount = function() {
    var result = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.data.length; i++) {
        if ($scope.data[i].winner == "Jack") {
            result++;
        }
    }
    return result;
});
```

and in your template:

```
{{ jackWinCount() }}
```

Answer (score 0):

If u want to filter data in angular you can used filter on array to filter the data

Below is the example:

```
$scop.newFilterData=$filter("filter")($scope.data , {"winner": "Jill"});
{{$scop.newFilterData.length}}
```